# Get the element's original font-size using beautiful soup 4

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am writing a python script where I am using BeautifulSoup4 to get the style of the element but the element doesn't has an explicit 'font-size' attribute in its style in the `em` format. I still want to get the font-size of this element whatever that is regardless of whereever it is being inherited from.

I can't seem to do that using BS4 or is there a way?

I feel it might be possible to do using selenium but is there a way to pass python bs4 element to selenium in python as my entire application is dependent on bs4.

Comment: `driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + htmlString)`

Comment: you can't do this with `BS4` because it works only with `HTML` but font size depends on `CSS` and how browser will render it. So you need to render it (using `Selenium` or similar) and later use `JavaScript` to get this value.